# Outlook Settings - Saving "Expand All Groups"

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, microsoft-office-2007

I have several folders in Outlook that I have sorted based on importance, date, etc. How can I ensure that every time I visit that folder that the groups remain expanded? For instance, if I delete all items of normal or low importance, the next time I get items with normal or low importance, the group is collapsed. I'm running Outlook 2007.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I think you're out of luck on this one.  Memory of expanded groups (or lack thereof) is one of the bigger annoyances of mine.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I thought, but I wasn't 100% sure.

Answer (score 3):

There is an easy way to make this work by default and not have to expand each time.  Go to view > arrange by > custom > group by

At the very bottom there is a drop down that let's you default to expanded view.  Once this is set you will always default expanded.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

View | Current View | Customize Current View | Group By | Expand/collapse defaults | All Expanded

Answer (score 0):

The best workaround I've found is to use the CTRL+PLUS keyboard shortcut for Expand All Groups

Answer (score 0):

This works for Outlook 14 - to collapse/expand Groups in a folder:

1. Access the Folder that has Groups expanded.
2. *View* menu → *View settings* → *Group by...* button → uncheck *Automatically group according to arrangement* → OK → OK.

Groups will collapse now.